# Build json object include array object in PostgreSQL single query

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-16

I have table  `level_one_table` `level_two_table` `level_three_table`

`level_one_table` to `level_two_table` one to multiple rows
`level_two_table` to `level_three_table` one to one row

Goal:  select them all return data like below:

```
{
  "level_one_table": {
     "id": ..,
     "... all other field in level_one_table"
     
    "level_two_table": [{
       "id": ..,
       "... all other field in level_two_table",
       
       "level_three_table": {
          "id": ..,
          "... all other field in level_three_table"
       }
    }]
  }
}
```

`level_one_table`:

| "id" | ... |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |

`level_two_table`:

| "id" | "fk_level_one_id" | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ... |
| 2 | 1 | ... |

`level_two_table`:

| "id" | "fk_level_two_id" | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ... |
| 2 | 2 | ... |

I used loop to select level two and level three table, is there a way to make it in single query?

I tried `json_build_object` but I dont know how to select `level_two_table` multiple rows make it as array object? and also select more deep `level_three_table` an object?

```
SELECT json_build_object(
  'id', t0.id,
  'level_two_table': t2.*
   ?? make level_three_table inside level_two_table as an object
) FROM level_one_table t0 
  LEFT JOIN level_two_table t1 ON t0.id = t1.fk_level_one_id
  LEFT JOIN level_three_table t2 ON t1.id = t2.fk_level_two_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested calls to `jon_build_object` are supported in postgres.

You need to build the expression step by step starting from the most nested objects. Note that the expression is somehow similar to the result.

`jsonb_pretty()` used here to get a nice output

```
select jsonb_pretty(
          json_build_object(
                'level_one_table',
                 json_build_object(
                     'id', t0.id,
                     'level_two_table',
                      json_arrayagg(
                        json_build_object(
                          'id', t1.id,
                          'colmun2', t1.colmun2,
                          'level_three_table',
                          json_build_object(
                            'id', t2.id,
                            'colmun3', t2.colmun3
                          )
                        )
                     )
                 )
          )::jsonb
       ) as json_obj
from level_one_table t0 
left join level_two_table t1 ON t0.id = t1.fk_level_one_id
left join level_three_table t2 ON t1.id = t2.fk_level_two_id
group by t0.id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/G4kxZz4D)

Comment: wooo thank you so much!! learn `json_bulid_object` can write like this now and `json_arrayagg` and must  add `group by`  .  all so useful ^^

Comment: Glad to hear I could help :)